# Generate and compile name to index translation/mapping for faster reusability

Tags: c#, compilation, generated-code

Suppose I get data from a service (that I can't control) as:

```
public class Data
{
    // an array of column names
    public string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }

    // an array of rows that contain arrays of strings as column values
    public string[][] Rows { get; get; }
}
```

and on the middle tier I would like to map/translate this to an `IEnumerable<Entity>` where column names in `Data` **may be** represented as properties in my `Entity` class. I said *may* because I may not need all the data returned by the service but just some of it.

### Transformation

This is an abstraction of an algorithm that would do the translation:

1. create an `IDictionary<string, int>` of `ColumnNames` so I can easily map individual column names to array indices in individual rows.
2. use reflection to examine my `Entity` properties' names so I'm able to match them with column names
3. iterate through `Data.Rows` and create my `Entity` objects and populate properties according to mapping done in #1. Likely using reflection and `SetValue` on properties to set them.

### Optimisation

Upper algorithm would of course work, but I think that because it uses reflection it should do some caching and possibly some on the fly compilation, that could speed things up considerably.

When steps 1 and 2 are done, we could actually generate a method that takes an array of strings and instantiates my entities using indices directly and compile it **and cache it** for future reuse.

I'm usually getting a page of results, so subsequent requests would reuse the same compiled method.

### Additional fact

This is not imperative to the question (and answers) but I also created two attributes that help with column-to-property mapping when these don't match in names. I created the most obvious `MapNameAttribute` (that takes a string and optionally also enable case sensitivity) and `IgnoreMappingAttribute` for properties on my `Entity` that shouldn't map to any data. But these attributes are read in step 2 of the upper algorithm so property names are collected and renamed according to this declarative metadata so they match column names.

### Question

What is the best and easiest way to generate and compile such a method? Lambda expressions? `CSharpCodeProvider` class?

Do you maybe have an example of generated and compiled code that does a similar thing? I guess that mappings are a rather common scenario.

> **Note**: In the meantime I will be examining PetaPoco (and maybe also Massive) because afaik they both do compilation and caching on the fly exactly for mapping purposes.

Comment: Would [FastMember](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html) be any use here? or possibly just look at how it works? (all the code is available)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes Mark, that's exactly what I'm after. Very nice package basically. :) Can you put this into an answer and also provide some additional information about caching that's done in your mini-lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: [obtain FastMember from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember)

Then just use:

```
var accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(Entity));
```

Then just in your loop, when you have found the `memberName` and `newValue` for the current iteration:

```
accessor[obj, memberName] = newValue;
```

This is designed to do what you are asking; internally, it maintains a set of types if has seen before. When a new type is seen, it creates a new subclass of `TypeAccessor` on-the-fly (via `TypeBuilder`) and caches it. Each unique `TypeAccessor` is aware of the properties for that type, and *basically* just acts like a:

```
switch(memberName) {
    case "Foo": obj.Foo = (int)newValue;
    case "Bar": obj.Bar = (string)newValue;
    // etc
}
```

Because this is cached, you only pay any cost (and not really a *big* cost) the first time it ever sees your type; the rest of the time, it is free. Because it uses `ILGenerator` *directly*, it also avoids any unnecessary abstraction, for example via `Expression` or CodeDom, so it is about as fast as it can be.

(I should also clarify that for `dynamic` types, i.e. types that implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, it can use a single instance to support every object).

---

Additional:

What you *could* do is: take the existing `FastMember` code, and edit it to process `MapNameAttribute` and `IgnoreMappingAttribute` during `WriteGetter` and  `WriteSetter`; then all the voodoo happens on your *data* names, rather than the *member* names.

This would mean changing the lines:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, prop.Name);
```

and

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, field.Name);
```

in both `WriteGetter` and `WriteSetter`, and doing a `continue` at the start of the `foreach` loops if it should be ignored.

Comment: +1 and accepted because it's too good. :) Thanks Mark. I may as well do a bit of other changes like remove direct casting and rather use `Convert` or `type.TryParse` methods because my data is always represented as strings... Casting is recommended when you know types match in other cases use `Convert`...